# Borderline off-topic question - is it, or is it not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

I stumble upon a [unique question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076766/disable-ipv6-loopback-on-windows-7-64-bit); *unique* because I don't recall previously seen one similar to this. The question basically asks how to troubleshoot a *Windows* error because one of the software development/testing tools isn't working.

Even though the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) states "*practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession*"; however, due to the fact that the error relates to a software **used** in the programming profession - does it qualify as on-topic?

Moreover, the question does have [one *possibly* good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148021/238722), but I think it would generate **much** better answers over at SuperUser.SE.

What's the consensus in these borderline off-topic situations? What are the general guidelines to follow?

Comment: FWIW, it's still young enough to migrate.

Comment: It's *very* vaguely related, but I don't think it's on-topic enough to stay. It's only relation to programming is that it needs to be turned off in order for his things to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The question basically asks how to troubleshoot a *Windows* error because one of the software development/testing tools isn't working.

I'd say move to Super User, because like you said, the question is not about the Selenium framework, but about a networking issue in Windows. There is a small bit about getting Selenium to play along with this particular issue, and it's not clear what the asker really wants to achieve, but based on the overall gist of the question and its answers, it seems to be more of a Windows question.

Comment: BoltClock, given that you're a mod, and *now* you're aware of this question - should we/I still flag it?

Comment: I'm currently discussing this with the Super User mods, but you can leave a flag in the meantime if you'd like.